# Google FIT APIS, Fitness history API for REST webservices

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, restful-architecture, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I see that google fit has Fitness History API available in set of Fit andriod APIs. This API provides daily activity data (Read daily total data) as mentioned in documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history). However, when I observe the RESTFUL webservices, I do not see any API that provides daily steps/activity data grouped by sources. Is such API not available via RESTFUL webservices and only available for andriod and not web?

Comment: I believe you can [retrieve the data](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/data-sources) assuming that the data source exists. You'd most likely have to create your own data sources if you want to track specific types of data.